# Loop through pandas grouped data index

Tags: python, pandas

Struggling newbie, we are trying to list the items of a grouped dataframe.
To highlight the problem please see a simplified example below.
First group the items:

```
data = {'colour': ['red','purple','green','purple','blue','red'], 'item': ['hat','scarf','belt','belt','hat','scarf'], 'material': ['felt','wool','leather','wool','plastic','wool']}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
grpd_df = df.groupby(df['item']).apply(lambda df:df.reset_index(drop=True))
grpd_df

          colour  item material
item

belt   0  green   belt  leather 
       1 purple  belt  wool 

hat    0 red     hat   felt 
       1 blue    hat   plastic 

scarf  0 purple  scarf wool 
       1 red     scarf wool
```

Then find all the rows that have a red item

```
df = grpd_df[grpd_df['colour'].eq('red').groupby(level=0).transform('any')]
print (df)

          colour   item material
item                           
hat    0     red    hat     felt
       1    blue    hat  plastic
scarf  0  purple  scarf     wool
       1     red  scarf     wool
```

We would like to then loop over a list of the items in the grpd_df i.e. hat and scarf. We've tried a `df.index.levels` but this outputs all the items including belt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `IndexSlice` and `get_level_values`, to achieve it .

```
grpd_df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[list(set(df.index.get_level_values(0).tolist())),:]]
Out[302]: 
         colour   item material
item                           
hat   0     red    hat     felt
      1    blue    hat  plastic
scarf 0  purple  scarf     wool
      1     red  scarf     wool
```

If need the level of the index from df

```
set(df.index.get_level_values(0).tolist())
Out[303]: {'hat', 'scarf'}
```